# Maintain an overlay directory in a separate git repository

Tags: git

Scenario:

- There is a repository CODE that I contribute code to.
- CODE contains only files that are shared between all developers
- When I work on my private CODE clone, I need project files for my IDE. But IDE-specific project files are not allowed to go to the upstream CODE repo.
- Project files are all located in a separate folder tree under CODE's root. They do not overlap
- I want to keep my project files under version control in a PROJECTFILES repository
- PROJECTFILES should reflect the branch structure of CODE
- Whenever I make a commit to CODE and something has changed in my project files, there should be a commit to PROJECTFILES as well.
- Whenever I change PROJECTFILES without changing CODE, I only want to update the link between the repositories.
- Whenever I pull new changes from upstream CODE, I might need to update PROJECTFILES, but it's up to me to do that. Otherwise PROJECTFILES should point to the nearest synced commit.
- I do not really want to maintain the two repositories separately. CODE is my master repository and it is the one where I want to specify refs. PROJECTFILES is kind of a slave and should just follow CODE.

Is there any solution for that scenario? I searched for git overlay and synchronizing git repositories, but couldn't find an adequate solution. Git subtree seems not what I am looking for. Or should I maybe make CODE a subtree of PROJECTFILES?

Comment: What do you mean by overlay?

Comment: What you are looking for is **technically possible** but likely requires a prohibitive amount of engineering effort, if we take all of your requirements at face value. While this problem isn’t remotely unique, there are a lot of unanswered questions like “how does `git bisect` work” which do not have straightforward or natural solutions. On the other hand, depending on how comfortable you are with `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` you might find it most convenient to maintain IDE files in private branches—this may be what you ultimately want, but it doesn't meet the requirements as written.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. I thought that this problem would be more common, but wasn't able to express it in adequate terms. I was quite confident that there must exist some best practices. But it appears, that working in private branches and rebasing/cherry-picking is widely used. I find that a bit unfomfortable though.

`git bisect` in my setup would always operate on CODE and once you roll back to a certain commit, it would try to find an adequate commit in PROJECTFILES. That should be possible because my repos have 0 physical overlap.